# PHP loop and IF condition

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

Hi I have two arrays and I want to check them if they have any element equal (same) with each other and if they have they should get on the page if not just print No.

I have made this code but i do not know why it doesn't work.

P.S. the elements of arrays contain text.

```
$res = count($title1);

for ($j = 0; $j <= $res; $j++) {
   if(strtoupper($title2[$j]) == strtoupper($title1[$j]))
    {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $title2[$j].'==='.$title1[$j].'<br/';
    }
   else{
        echo 'No<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What are you expecting your code to do and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Can you give some sample input and expected output which you need ?

Comment: Your code requires that not only do they both have the same value, but they also have to have the same index for that value.  So, if one has "Joe" at index 0 and the other has "Joe" at index 1, they will be considered as not matching.  If that is the requirement, then it seems you have it right, but if you need to check every value of each array for matches, then the answers from others should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if(in_array($value , $array2)
    {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $value;
        $count = $count + 1 ;
    }
}
```

this is the right answer :) thnx @hamidreza

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too

```
<?php
$count = 0
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if(in_array($value , $array2)
    {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $value;
        $count = $count + 1 ;
    }
}
if($count == 0 )
{
    echo "no" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$cout = $count + 1 ;` (typo) should read as `$count = $count + 1 ;`

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, as we don't know what the arrays contain, but I assume you want to check if they have the same element *at any index.*  At the moment, you are only checking if `$title1` has the same element as `$title2` at the same index.  So if you have two arrays

```
['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']
```

It checks if `'A' == 'B'` and then if `'B' == 'A'`.

What you need to do is something like:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($title1); $j++) {
   for ($k = 0; $k < count($title2); $k++) {
     if(strtoupper($title2[$k]) == strtoupper($title1[$j]))
     {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $title2[$j].'==='.$title1[$j].'<br/>';
     }
     else {
        echo 'No<br/>';
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: why are you looping through both arrays? this is `O(n^2)`. You can just loop through first array and check if its set in another array. Also your code will result in undefined index error message at last iteration. See my answer

Comment: I'm looping through both because, as my answer stated, it checks if the item exists *at any position* in the other array.  The <= was just from copy pasting their loop, didn't notice that, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are using **<=** instead of **<**. If you are looping through array count and you are using **<=** it will go over the array bounds. If your array contains 4 elements, the last array value is at index 3: `$arr[3]` (fourth position) but you are trying to get the value on `$arr[4]` at the last iteration which would cause error. You should check your error_log.

Try this:

```
$res = count($title1);

for ($j = 0; $j < $res; $j++) {
    //you need to check to see if $j'th position is available in $title2 array
    if(isset($title2[$j]) && strtoupper($title2[$j]) == strtoupper($title1[$j]))
    {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $title2[$j].'==='.$title1[$j].'<br/';
    }
    else{
        echo 'No<br/>';
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($title1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($title2[$key]) && 
        strtoupper($title2[$key]) == strtoupper($title1[$key])) {
        echo 'Yes<br/>';
        echo $title2[$key].'==='.$title1[$key].'<br/';
    }
    else {
        echo 'No<br/>';
    }
}
```